# HOC: type parameter `Props` of function call. Missing annotation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

```
type ButtonProps = {
  children: React.Node,
  href: string,
  onClick: Function,
};

const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => (
  <a href={props.href} onClick={props.onClick}>
    <button type="submit">
      <span>{props.children}</span>
    </button>
  </a>
);

function hoc<Props: {}>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Props>,
): React.ComponentType<Props> {
  return function WrapperComponent(props: Props) {
    return <Component {...props} />;
  };
}

export default hoc(Button);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a generic higher order component that can wrap *any* class component as well as stateless functional components. Above simplified implementation is pretty much taken from https://flow.org/en/docs/react/hoc/.

This gives me the following error, which I don't fully understand as I'm under the impression that I'm following the example supplied in the docs:

```
type parameter `Props` of function call. Missing annotation
```

[Reproducible example on try](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQMAnmFnAEICuMMEAdgArEw6ALxwA3nThxcAC2AAbACaVeALkxUYAOgByEJVgA0UuLMoENqGFGC8A5iel8AwguC4A1hoBiHXvjAfCYAvvR0uHzW7Fw8vHBiABRgQqganNx8ghDCAJQJAHxwiaYAPMhmFiLiKTmo2uZYBCFwru5e1bXC2m0eniEFptKlAEaxfEPScEwsIgBEqBwjIMAwc5ODU1OlqGDIvAU1qdpyiipYvCGlAPS7+5vb12OZB2XXyIO54QT+gXxmEFwpWywg04gGJWkLhIkF4FxgGmweB00PAfHhABVmFhgakCiZcoitNpUbDMdjcXUipJpJQYBwoPEfgEYEF4gB1KDIMAsKCk9G8GDJVIaEGofI0qZ0hnxUr8uGCiTaZVdVAta4FejSMJ0EJ0OhYAAekFgcEMBGQHAU8FkgMSGTiXyAA)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like others reported this bug, too: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4905

Seems to have very recently been fixed (v0.55): https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4709#issuecomment-334555165

Comment: There is no prop insertion going on so I'm not sure how `$Diff` would help in this particular situation.

Comment: @Eelke that part is irrelevant for your issue, if you look at the OP on my second link the example case is almost exactly yours. Seems like there was a bug exporting HOC-style types

Comment: Seems that it's not fixed in my case, as the above flow.try link is on version 0.56 and still errors